I cannot identify/find the connector type/manufacturer
I'm looking for 7pin single row crimp connector for to replace a damaged one on wiring harness.
All information I have so far is on picture and the board model is Argus850 (very left connector - J9, next to J13), I know it's not much but maybe someone dealt with that already - they are all of the same type with different #pins. J4 on the right has a labeled plug which hard to read. The connector can withhold at least 120VAC.
I looked at the TE, AMP - nothing.

Thank you for any info!

I think you mean right-most connector?  Can you add some measurements?

Whenever asking about rectangular connector identification: What is connector pitch and how to measure it?

Additional info for anyone searching for this: pitch is 5 mm, except for pin #1:  7.5 mm.  That's the same as the JST "V" connector. But that connector us shroudless. This one isn't. Housing shape: trapezoidal ("D"). (Unfortunately, it's not in my database of connectors.)

@evildemonic - yes, but eventually they are all the same type. Unfortunately I don't have that board yet, just a model name and then I looked on ebay and took a snip.
Lundin - thank you - will look into it.
DavideAndrea - ok - i'll use in search. Yes the connector/plug body is like with beveled end. Thanks!

I found this site https://www.atd-shop.com/qx231H-en/crimp-connectors-rm%3D508mm
Parts may not be available but anyway the case can be closed.
Thanks to all the participants!

How the Heck did you find it? Please tell us about your search process.

)) @DavideAndrea you gave me the idea how i can search.
